# How to publish app for specified people in Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I need to add an application to the Google play store for specified people,

- No one can show the app on the Google Play Store result
- Or the user will get join

Note: I need solution different from **testers list** and add the emails to the app testers

How can I handle this process?

Update: My app community are hospitals, and I have their emails,
I need only them to download and update the application, Alpha/Beta/.. are testing releases (user will show some UI that they are dealing with testing releases)

Comment: Can you describe in your question more about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Christian updated!

Answer (score 2):

This is what [Alpha/Beta/Closed testing tracks](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) are for.

Update:
For the problem addressed in the question - this is known as the "Enterprise" case. There are various options in Google Play for this, [which are described here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/work).

Comment: My app community are only hospitals, I need the app available for only those clients (I have their emails)
and Alpha/Beta/Closed testing tracks are testing releases(users will be notified that they are dealing with App not final)

Comment: This is an enterprise use case. You probably want to look at the Google Play enterprise solutions. Modified answer

Comment: Thanks, I will check and back to you soon